# Difference between the headers x-correlation-id, request-id, request-context and traceparent

Tags: angular, azure-application-insights, opentracing, distributed-tracing

I have an angular application calling server api's.

I have enabled distrubuted tracing using application insights sdk `"@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.5.4"` enabling **W3C** tracing mode and see the End-To-End request trace in Azure Application insights.

I am not sure what is the difference between these headers: `x-correlation-id`, `request-id`, `request-context` and `traceparent`. Doesn't traceparent contain all that within ?

sample initialition code

```
this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
    config: {
      instrumentationKey: settings.appInsightsConfig.instrumentationKey,
      distributedTracingMode: DistributedTracingModes.W3C,
      disableCorrelationHeaders: false,
      enableDebug: false,
      enableCorsCorrelation: true,
      enableRequestHeaderTracking: true,
      enableAutoRouteTracking: true,
      autoTrackPageVisitTime: true,
      enableAjaxErrorStatusText: true
    }
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: [Telemetry correlation in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation)

Comment: as i implied before, this link is not useful –